# Python re.sub() failure on multiline string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.6, multiline

I have a portion of a script that looks like something along the lines of this...

```
import re, sys
print(sys.version) # so you can see my Python version

repl = (
    "use bravo\\api\\resources\\usersResource;\n"
    "use bravo\\api\\resources\\groupsResource;\n"
    "use bravo\\api\\resources\\bandsResource;\n"
    "use bravo\\api\\resources\\setlistsResource;\n"
    "use bravo\\api\\resources\\songsResource;"
)

pattern = r'\{\{\$use_table_resources\}\}'
string = "{{$use_table_resources}}"

re.sub(pattern, repl, string)
```

Whenever I run it, I get the following output and error:

```
3.6.2 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep 19 2017, 08:03:39) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    re.sub(pattern, repl, string)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 191, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 326, in _subx
    template = _compile_repl(template, pattern)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 317, in _compile_repl
    return sre_parse.parse_template(repl, pattern)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 904, in parse_template
    raise s.error("missing <")
sre_constants.error: missing < at position 64 (line 2, column 26)
```

This works sometimes when I make the `repl` replacement string shorter, but I really can't figure it out. As far as I can tell, I'm working within their constraints, according to the [re.sub(...) API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

I know that this simple case would not justify the use of regex, but this snippet of code is taken out of a much larger piece of software. I don't need any answers telling me that regex is the wrong approach, because this is actually the simplest case I could produce that still reproduce the problem. There ***are*** more complicated instances where I need RegEx to actually do its job.

Either way, I think somehow the problem is in the contents of the replacement string, as odd as that sounds. when I use shorter replacement strings, I don't encounter this error.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated. This is probably something really tiny and stupid, but I've already come back to this a few times, and I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there isn't enough escaping in your replacement string, so the backslashes are interpreted by regex engine as a start of captured group (like the classical `r"\1"` or `"\\1"` without raw prefix).

You could add the raw prefix before each string, but I'd rather use multi-line *raw* strings like this (easier to read):

```
repl = r"""use bravo\\api\\resources\\usersResource;
use bravo\\api\\resources\\groupsResource;
use bravo\\api\\resources\\bandsResource;
use bravo\\api\\resources\\setlistsResource;
use bravo\\api\\resources\\songsResource;
"""
```

then the resulting replacement is

```
use bravo\api\resources\usersResource;
use bravo\api\resources\groupsResource;
use bravo\api\resources\bandsResource;
use bravo\api\resources\setlistsResource;
use bravo\api\resources\songsResource;
```

Now, without changing the input:

using `re.escape` like `re.sub(pattern, re.escape(repl), string)` doesn't work that well because space and end of lines are also escaped

But you can do this since you know that the only problematic chars are the backslashes:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl.replace("\\",r"\\"), string)
```

(it replaces the backslashes by double backslashes and the output is the same)

Comment: Do you know of an easy way to escape the replacement? The replacement text in the rest of my program is generated from some another text source.

Comment: Many thanks, sir! I've been chasing this rabbit for almost an entire day now

Comment: you're welcome. That took me longer than expected myself. Damn regexes :)